# /usr/local/bin/php: not found when installing PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I tried to install `pear` with this command:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

But I got this error:

> /usr/local/bin/pear: 28: exec: /usr/local/bin/php: not found

Comment: Cleaned up formatting and improved title.

Answer (score 0):

if you are a mac user
**add the following line into the ~/.bash_profile**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

if this is still not working 
please in the terminal type these command and post your console info

```
$ echo $PATH
$ php-v
```

Comment: my os is ubntu ,echo $path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin and php -v PHP 7.1.11-1+ubuntu17.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 

Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.11-1+ubuntu17.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies